# Cant figure out how to merge variables vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a for each loop to take the words from a string and place them each into a text box. The program allows for up to "9" variables What I am trying to attempt is.

`Foreach word in Words 
i = i +1 
Varible & i = word 
txtCritical1.Text = variable & i`

any ideas on a way to make this work?

Comment: What do you expect for a behaviour? An example of what Words might be would help (a string?). And what 'Varible & i = word' is supposed to do?

Comment: I posted an answer to my issue below , Thanks for the -1 whomever you are xD

Answer (score 0):

Have a look through the MSDN article on For Each. It includes a sample using strings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So i went with a simple if statement this does the trick. Each text box is filled in.

```
 Dim details As String = EditEvent.EditDbTable.Rows(0).Item(13).ToString()


            Dim words As String() = details.Split(New Char() {"«"})


            Dim word As String
            For Each word In words

                i = i + 1
                v = word



                If i = 1 Then
                    txtCritical1.Text = v
                ElseIf i = 2 Then
                    txtCritical2.Text = v
                ElseIf ....
                ElseIf i = 9 then
                    txtCritical2.text = v
                Else
                 ....
                End If

            Next
```

Comment: Put your txtCritical in an array, and you'll be able to assign them direcly with `txtCritical[i] = v` that will look nicer

Comment: How would i make that change the textbox?

Comment: For you best control is [DataGridVIew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)